# The query contains references to items defined on a different data context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I read couple of another posts in Stackoverflow but my problem is simple and different. I have 2 separate databases and thats why I have two separate Datacontext. Here is my query in which I am passing parameters and binding it to my GridView:

```
if (Session["EntitySelected"] == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Entity first!");
    Response.Redirect("~/FrontEnd/List.aspx");
}
int getEntity = Int16.Parse(Session["EntitySelected"].ToString());
this.Label3.Text = "You Selected Entity: " + (string)Session["EntitySelected"];

dbWebEnrollDataContext dt1 = new dbWebEnrollDataContext();
CommissionsV2DataContext cv1 = new CommissionsV2DataContext();
var td = from s in cv1.Entity_Product_Points
         join r in dt1.PlanMasters on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
         where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
         select new
         {
             s.Product_ID,
             r.PlanName,
             s.HiCommission,
             s.HiCommissionOld,
             s.LowCommission,
             s.LowCommissionOld
         };
gvShowComm.DataSource = td;
gvShowComm.DataBind();
```

As expected it is throwing me this error. But I did the same while I am adding a record into the a table of 1 database. It is inserting row but also throwing the same error. Whats the look around? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you should be doing a join across two data contexts. From the look of your LINQ query, you're not even using r from your join query to produce anything meaningful; it looks like you can just query `cv1` and get your data:

```
var td = cv1.Entity_Product_Points.Where(x => x.Entity_ID == getEntity);
// Call ToList to fully enumerate the set.
```

EDIT: Looking up a solution, it seems like it might be just as easy as marking each data context query AsQueryable to get the [solution](http://jasonheine.com/2009/05/25/linq-cross-data-context-a-solution/).

Comment: Can one DataContext hold two different table from two different Databases?

Comment: Pls see my edit. I made a change which is showing where I am using 'r'