# Can we do cross join in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So basically I asked this question while back:

[The query contains references to items defined on a different data context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572642/the-query-contains-references-to-items-defined-on-a-different-data-context)

But this time I am doing it in EF. Does EF supports cross joining between two tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do joins between different data context's. You would have to do the join with linq-objects

```
var crossJoin = from a in context.TableA.AsEnumerable()
                from b in context2.TableB.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                  a,
                  b
                };
```

Comment: This is in single data context. Its not in querying two different data context like I mentioned in the link.

Comment: @Gator: Just to make this clear. Updated answer uses linq-to-object cross join = it loads all data from tableA and tableB to your application and if your query contains any `Where` or any other clause it will be performed in your application, not in the database.

Comment: This is not between two contexts since each is being "executed" with .AsEnuerable()

Answer (score 1):

No entity framework query can cross boundary of single context. So cross join is supported as @Aducci showed in his response but cross context or cross database linq-to-entities queries are not supported.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, which is "no", but you can join two different lists of objects as long as they've been "executed". As noted, it will do filtering in the application not the database, which needs to be considered

Answer (score 0):

Using EF Core 2.0 and ASPNET Core 2.0.  You can [indeed cross-join using this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations).  Notice the NonEquijoin example.