# How should i declare Foreign key (UserId) relationships with the default created MVC .NET Memberships/Users tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-migrations

What comes to mind is doing something like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    // Additional user info
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'User' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Users'
>   is based on type 'User' that has no keys defined.

What point I am missing? isn't there anyway to write a class that is automatically migrated to sql table (Code First)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need the [Key] annotation if it is unclear what is the primary key. But the convention is that it the classname ending with Id and the you need a UserId property in the User class. So IMHO I think it should be something like this:

```
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        public UserProfileId
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        // Additional user info
    }
```

> What point I am missing? isn't there anyway to write a class that is
>   automatically migrated to sql table (Code First)?

Yes when your code needs the use the class it will be created or you can use scaffolding. 
I use the migration tool now to force a quick creation of all the tables. See eg here [MSDN article about migration tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)
[Blog about migration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: 1) I need [ForeignKey("UserId")] public virtual User User { get; set; } equals [ForeignKey("User")] public Guid UserId { get; set; }
2) I want the User to be Foreign Key + primary Key
3) I still get same error

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by: User be Foreign Key + primary key. Your User primary key has to be like an unique integer or a unique string? Now your User is an object. Can you show how you want your tables to be?

Comment: MVC4 creates few tables for you that manage your users, e.g Users, Memberships, Roles. The Users are identified by UserId key that is found in these tables. I want to have another table that references the UserId identifier in order to include other user information. I want to reference it in my Class so I will always migrate to database with Code First approach. Never mind the Foreign Key + Key.

Comment: Or is it that you have a one - to - on relationship between user and userprofile? According to this blogpost you must use fluent API instead. https://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/configuring-entity-framework-4-codefirst/

Comment: I am talking about a specific table in the SQL. I am searching if Memberships/Roles/Users auto generated SQL Tables by .NET have any class representation in code that I can use.

Comment: Is your Default Membership Provider database and the DBContext database now in the same database? If not look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953218/move-my-code-first-entity-framework-created-database-to-the-default-membership-p   and as they suggest: http://efmembership.codeplex.com/