# Is it possible to connect an Asp.net MVC web application with more than one databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to develop a new asp.net MVC web application but this application should be able to :-

- perform CRUD operations on an already existing web application Database that is deployed on the same server as the asp.net mvc.
- Also the asp.net MVC web application should have its own database .

All the MVC projects I have implemented so far were either, using their own database or were build on existing database.

But will it be possible to build a new asp.net mvc application on existing database to retrieve data, insert data and delete data;  But at the same time to have its own database.
Baring in mind that  I am using the entity framework as the data access layer.
BR

Comment: but usually when I create entity framework object I select the database I want to integrate with ,, so in this case I will have multiple context objects?

Comment: Indeed, two contexts that you open when you need it, and close as soon as possible.

Comment: Cross-context operations will be fun, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572642/the-query-contains-references-to-items-defined-on-a-different-data-context

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You will need to create a Entity Framework model for each database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible regardless of the framework you use to connect to the databases, ADO.NET, EF, etc.

I would have a separate DAL project containing all the DAL logic and some kind of DBFactory class returning the specific DBContext according to where the data is going to be retrieved from.

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
      using(var dbContext = DBFactory.GetContext(EDbConnecion.SQLSERVER) )
      {
          //regular LINQ code here

      } 
}
```

And the only job of the DBFactory.GetContext method is something like:

```
public static DbContext DBFactory.GetContext(EDbConnection connType)
{
     switch(connType)
     {
         case EDbConnecion.SQLSERVER:
           return new SqlServerContext("WhatHaveYou");
         case EDbConnecion.ORACLE:
           return new OracleContext("WhatHaveYou");
         //and so on
     }
}
```